# reference between filed in tuleap artefact

Tags: tuleap

I would like to know if there is a possibility to have reference between fields on an artefact.

For example, if I have a field id, I would like to have an automaticc text which will be http://mysite/"id", with "id" the value entered on the "id" field. The perfect think will be that the result field would be in HTML(to use

Thank you for your answer.

Mickaël

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such functionality in Tuleap. You could possibly use a somewhat unsightly hack using cross-references:

First define a cross-reference pattern in your project administration:

-keyword : mysite

-description : link to a lovely page

-nature : other

-link: http://mysite/$1

Then, in your artifact, use the cross-reference in any text field, e.g. "Click on my page mysite #id to see it"